# SYSDATETIME going backwards

Tags: sql, sql-server, timing, datediff, sysdatetime

**First up**, I have solved the actual problem that I had, by moving to using a datetime2, and DATEDIFFing at the MICROSECOND scale. But I'm still surprised by the behaviour I was seeing, so ....

---

I'm trying to diagnose a perf issue with some SQL, and I have code that loops like this to test it:

```
DECLARE @timer datetime = NULL
DECLARE @diff int = 0
DECLARE @total int = 0

WHILE(<condition>)
BEGIN
    SET @timer = SYSDATETIME()
    <select statement under test>
    SET @diff = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @timer, SYSDATETIME())
    SET @total = @total + @diff
END

SELECT @total
```

I'm getting **NEGATIVE** totals, though !?

How the hell is *that* a thing?
I would understand ending up with `@total = 0`; that's saying that the increments are <1 ms (or close enough that the resolution of the timer reports that, anyway) so that I end up summing lots of 0s.

But it seems enormously bugged for it to possible for the DATEDIFF to return ***negative***!

I checked further and confirmed that the `@diff` variable is indeed returning `-1` and even `-2`.

What gives?

Comment: @GordonLinoff True. Corrected. They were of course initialised in the real code that I have trimmed down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SYSDATETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetime-transact-sql) returns a `datetime2` with `7`digits of precision.

You are assigning it to a `datetime` variable with only precision of approx `1/300` per second. So it can get rounded up (or down but up is the cause here).

Try

```
DECLARE @SYSDATETIME DATETIME2 = '2017-04-15 14:49:36.001999'
DECLARE @timer DATETIME = @SYSDATETIME;
DECLARE @diff INT = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @timer, @SYSDATETIME);

SELECT @timer AS [@timer],
       @diff  AS [@diff];
```

This returns

```
+-------------------------+-------+
|         @timer          | @diff |
+-------------------------+-------+
| 2017-04-15 14:49:36.003 |    -2 |
+-------------------------+-------+
```

The `.001999` gets rounded to `.003` and that crosses two milisecond boundaries so `DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND` returns `-2` when comparing the rounded and non rounded values.

Comment: This seems like a classic answer.  Hope if receives many upvotes.

Comment: This answer also suggests that I don't correctly understand how `DATEDIFF` calculates it's answers? I would have expected `DATEDIFF(unit, 1.99, 3)` to return `1`, not `2`. Is it essentially going from `Floor_by_datepart(start)` to `Floor_by_datepart(end)`

Comment: @Brondahl it returns the number of datepart boundaries crossed. `DATEDIFF(YEAR, '20161231 23:59', '20170101 00:00')` returns 1 year even though it is only a minute. So yes.